# Trying to write Mysql query for my database

Tags: mysql, posts

Here is a image on my database http://oi46.tinypic.com/2eb5lpw.jpg

[image]

I wonder if it possible to get posts from "Meals" by restID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy:

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM meals m JOIN cats c ON m.catId=c.catId 
WHERE restId='theRestIdIWantToQuery'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible join all three tables

```
select * from restaurant r 
  inner join cats c on r.id=c.restId 
  inner join meals m on c.id = m.catID
  where r.id=YOURRESTID
```